# After an exception, keep on running

Tags: c#, exception, continue

For example:

```
 try
{
   Task1();
   Task2();
   Task3();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Right now if an exception occurs in Task1(), the code in Task2 and Task2 method does not run. The program stops.

How could I make it so when an exception occurs, the code / methods that below it would keep on running to the end.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want them to execute in this fashion, there's no point in putting them all in the try block together.

Comment: It is bad practice to do what you are trying to achieve. In each function create checks that would allow your code to avoid exceptions.

Comment: I assume that in your `catch` block you're actually doing something to handle the exception, but just haven't bothered to actually post what it is here (which is fine).  If you're not actually doing anything, and your `catch` blocks really are blank, then that's almost certainly wrong.  You don't want to be catching exceptions when you're not in a position to handle them.  You'll never know when your program isn't working right, or why it's not working right.

Comment: Guising the OP used "Task" as a general method name and had no intention of going down the `Task` / async path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An exception moves execution to the end of the try block and into the `catch` block.  To do what you want, you'd have to use separate `try/catch` blocks:

```
try
{
   Task1();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

try
{
   Task2();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

try
{
   Task3();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

You *could* put your tasks in a collection (provided they all have the same signature) and loop, but the net effect would be the same:

```
var tasks = new Action[] {Task1, Task2, Task3};
foreach(var task in tasks)
{
    try
    {
       task();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your collection idea seems interesting, how would you do it?

Comment: Guessing the OP didn't intend to use async related tasks. The first part of your answer is correct. Not so sure the second part is what they were looking for.

Comment: @andleer I am not using async tasks either - only generic `Action`s (which would fit the method signature(s) provided).   _Functionally_ it's the same effect - the gist of the question seems to be "how can I handle an exception but not break the flow of execution", which either methods addresses.

Comment: @DStanley Completely agree but think you are proposing a solution that is several orders of magnitude beyond where the OP is. Still a correct solution!

Comment: @andleer I think you're reading too much in - all I did was wrap three function calls into an array of `Action` delegates - no async, no threading, just plain old synchronous `Action` delegates.  Since the OP _asked_ about the collection piece I provided an example.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, in the code that you have, if there is an exception throw trying to **start** `Task1()` then the other two tasks are not started.  If that task is started without error but *results in a task that is in a `Faulted` state*, then your other tasks are properly started.

Generally one would not expect methods like these to throw an exception *starting* the task in most situations.  Null checking arguments is something commonly done, but other than that one would generally expect such methods to not fail to *start* the task.  If you have any control over the method, consider re-designing it so that it generates a faulted task instead of throwing an exception, unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

You may also want to create a method that takes a task-returning method and, if it fails to generate a task, instead creates a faulted task.  If it is successful, it can just return that task:

```
public static Task WrapExceptions(this Func<Task> function)
{
    try
    {
        return function();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        tcs.SetException(e);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

If you want to ensure all tasks are started even if there is an exception when starting the task, then you need to wrap each method call in its own try/catch.

Comment: Is there evidence that the OP wants to use the Task class?  I think he's just using Task1(), etc. as placeholder names for other methods he's calling.

Comment: @adv12 - Even if the OP doesn't want to use the `Task` class, this is still a good example of good design.  +1, Servy.

Comment: @Brandon: it's good design to replace three sequential, synchronous method calls with multi-threaded code without any knowledge of the contents of those method calls?  I think not.

Answer (score 4):

Put each statement in its own try-catch block:

```
try
{
   Task1();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
try {
   Task2();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
try {
   Task3();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```